# command to insert multiple values in a table from an excel file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

i have to make a program where i will read data from excel and i will store them in database.
I had managed to create the table that would have the name of each one excel file and create the fields of the table by the first row of the excel file. Now i have to store all the other data from the excel file in the table.
I had made the code below but i have error with the "insert" element.

```
private static String fillTable(Connection con, String fieldname, HashMap<String, Integer> tableFields){
        Iterator iter = tableFields.keySet().iterator();
        Iterator cells = tableFields.keySet().iterator(); 
        String str="";
        String[] tousFields = new String[tableFields.size()];
        int i = 1; 
        while (iter.hasNext()){
            String fieldName = (String) iter.next();
            Integer fieldType=(Integer)tableFields.get(fieldname);
            while (cells.hasNext()){
                String fieldName1 = (String) cells.next();
                Integer fieldType1=(Integer)tableFields.get(fieldName1);
                }
                tousFields[i++]= str;   
        }
        try
        {
            Statement  stmt = con.createStatement();
            System.out.println ( "Use the table");
            String all = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(tousFields, ",");
            String sql= INSERT INTO "tablename"  + VALUES (" +all +")";
            stmt.executeUpdate (sql);
```

I want all the columns and rows to be read. How i have to write the command in the INSERT?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What `error` do you get during `insert`. Post stacktrace.

Comment: @Apurv He is passing the values as +all +, thats not gonna work anyway.

Comment: yes, i have error in here : String sql= INSERT INTO "tablename"  + VALUES (" +all +")";

Answer (score 0):

Modify the sql line to look like the following.

```
 String sql= "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES (" +all +")";
```